# How to make this bound true if p=2

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

I'm trying to complete the proof of this [theorem, pag. 234](https://chagall.med.cornell.edu/BioinfoCourse/PDFs/Lecture4/random_number_generator.pdf). At the end of the proof, it says that for $p=2$, the proof is only *slightly different*. The problem with $p=2$ is that the argument made using the Legendre formula in $(5)$:

$$
v_p(j!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor\leq\frac{j}{p}+\frac{j}{p^2}+\frac{j}{p^3}+\cdots=\frac{j}{p-1}\leq j-1
$$

would not hold. So without that inequality, you cannot assure that $$\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$$ is divisible by $p^\alpha$ ($2^\alpha$ in this case). The Legendre formula is a key part of the proof because he uses to count the number of times $p$ can appear in $j$.

I know I have left out a lot of details because they are explained in the proof. If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the Legendre formula in its alternate form (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)) you have:

$$ \nu_2(j!) = j - s_2(j) \le j - 1$$

and also:

$$ \nu_2(j) \le \log_2{j} \le j-1 $$

for $j \gt 1$.